# How can I read a text file and get a string from every line in C++?

Tags: c++, ifstream

So; I'm trying to create kind of a hangman game, and I want to get the words from a .txt file I have downloaded from the internet with about 4900 words, each one in a different line. I'm trying to read the file, but the program exits every time with the error(1), that is no file found. I've tried using absolute path, and also placed the file in the working directory and used the relative path, but every time I get the same error. Could anyone take a look and tell me what's wrong with this?
I'm new in C++, I started learning with Java and now I want to try something new, so I'm not sure if there are some mistakes on the structure of the code. 
Thanks everyone!

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

vector<string> GetWords(){
    ifstream readLine;
    string currentWord;
    vector<string> wordList;

    readLine.open("nounlist.txt");

    while (getline(readLine, currentWord)) {
        wordList.push_back(currentWord);
    }


    if (!readLine) {
        cerr << "Unable to open text file";
        exit(1);
    }
    return wordList;
}
```

Comment: The if-statement will always be checked after readline is at the end, so it'll always output the error. If that's what you meant. Otherwise, I don't get any error when I try this, it reads the lines in properly.

Comment: @Jack of Blades is right, move `if(!readLine)...` above `while` loop.

Comment: Yeah there is no point checking if the file opened correctly *after* reading all the data. Best to do that immediately after trying to open it.

Comment: @JackOfBlades Makes sense. I thought it was some weird c++ business, and I just missed basic stuff. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You have checked readLine after reading all data. You may use the following code:

```
if (readLine.is_open()) {
    while (getline(readLine, currentWord)) {
        wordList.push_back(currentWord);
    }
    readLine.close();
} else {
    cerr << "Unable to open text file";
    exit(1);
}
```

is_open function is to check if readLine is associated with any file.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

```
std::ifstream readLine("nounlist.txt", std::ifstream::in);
if (readLine.good())
{
    while (getline(readLine, currentWord)) 
    {
        wordList.push_back(currentWord);
    }
}
```